# Grep Curl command's console output to a file

Tags: unix, curl

Need an help in doing grep of 3 variables from the curl commands console output.

By executing the below curl command i get some output which prints in the console itself. I need to grep some variables(say staus, name, url) and redirect it to a file.

curl -v -X POST -D tmp.txt -H "Content-Type:text/plain" --data "$SECRET" -H "Accept:application/xml" -H "Connection:close" http://google.com/api/search

Comment: curl ... | grep 'pattern' > filename

Comment: There are so many curl commands in my shell script. when i execute that script, its printing the output in console. I tried this suggested by you. i am trying grab the status code. but not all status codes are getting captured to a file

Answer (score 0):

Some of your responses must be going to stderr, try:

```
curl ... | grep 'pattern' &> filename
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommending using slightly different options to curl if you want to process the output.  If I were looking for the Expires header:

```
curl -si -X POST -H "Content-Type:text/plain" --data "$SECRET" -H "Accept:application/xml" -H "Connection:close" http://google.com/api/search
```

If you want the HTTP status, you can just do this:

```
curl -si -X POST -H "Content-Type:text/plain" --data "$SECRET" -H "Accept:application/xml" -H "Connection:close" http://google.com/api/search | head -1
```

That'll print `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently` -- add an `|awk '{print $2}'` to the end of that and you'll get only the numeric status.

Comment: Glad to hear it!  Please don't forget to accept an answer.